# sortable and filterable not work in dynamic data from api in DataTable vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

sortable and filterable not work in dynamic data from API in DataTable vuetify

its works for static data.

in laravel api :

```
 $posts = Post::select('id', 'title', 'type', 'active', 'category_id')
                    ->with('category')
                    ->where('author_id', $request['userId'])
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->paginate($size);
```

in client :

```
        <template>
          <main>
            <v-app>
              <!--breadcrumbs-->
              <breadcrumbs :breadcrumbs="breadcrumbs"></breadcrumbs>
              <!---->
              <!--actions-->
              <div class="actions container">
                <v-btn class="action__button" depressed color="success" @click="gotoNewCategory">
                  <v-icon dark> mdi-plus </v-icon>
                  insert category
                </v-btn>
              </div>
              <!---->
<v-card style="margin: 15px; padding: 10px">
        <v-text-field
          v-model="search"
          append-icon="mdi-magnify"
          label="search"
          single-line
          hide-details
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-card>

              <!--datatable-->
              <v-data-table
                :headers="headers"
                :items="categorys"
                :page="page"
                :pageCount="numberOfPages"
                :options.sync="options"
                :server-items-length="totalCategorys"
                :loading="loading"
:search="search"
                class="elevation-1"
                no-data-text="no data!"
                :footer-props="{
                  showFirstLastPage: true,
                  'items-per-page-text': 'test',
                  'items-per-page-all-text': 'all',
                  'page-text': '',
                }"
              >
                <template v-slot:top>
                  <v-dialog v-model="dialogDelete" max-width="500px">
                    <v-card>
                      <v-card-title class="headline">
    </v-card-title
                      >
                      <v-card-actions>
                        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                        <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="closeDelete">no</v-btn>
                        <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="deleteCategoryConfirm"
                          >yes</v-btn
                        >
                        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                      </v-card-actions>
                    </v-card>
                  </v-dialog>
                </template>
                <template v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
                  <td>
                    <v-icon small class="mr-2" @click="editCategory(item)"> mdi-pencil </v-icon>
        
                    <v-icon small @click="deleteCategory(item)"> mdi-delete </v-icon>
                  </td>
                </template>
              </v-data-table>
              <!---->
            </v-app>
          </main>
        </template>
        <script>
        import breadcrumbs from "~/components/breadcrumbs";
        
        export default {
          name: "categorys",
          layout: "dashboard",
          components: { breadcrumbs },
        
          data() {
            return {
search: "",
              page: 1,
              totalCategorys: 0,
              numberOfPages: 0,
              dialogDelete: false,
              editedIndex: -1,
              categoryIdForDelete: "",
              loading: true,
              options: {},
              headers: [
                { text: "ID", value: "id", align: "start" },
                { text: "categoryName", value: "categoryName", align: "start" },
                { text: "actions", value: "actions", sortable: false },
              ],
              categorys: [],
              
            };
          },
          //this one will populate new data set when user changes current page.
          watch: {
            options: {
              handler() {
                this.readDataFromAPI();
              },
            },
            deep: true,
          },
          methods: {
            readDataFromAPI() {
              this.loading = true;
              const { page, itemsPerPage, sortBy, sortDesc } = this.options;
              let pageNumber = page;
        
              this.$axios
                .get(
                  "/api/category/categories?size=" +
                    itemsPerPage +
                    "&page=" +
                    pageNumber +
                    "&sortby=" +
                    sortBy +
                    "&sortDesc=" +
                    sortDesc,
                  this.fields
                )
                .then((response) => {
                  this.loading = false;
                  this.categorys = response.data.result.data;
                  this.totalCategorys = response.data.result.total;
                  this.numberOfPages = Math.round(response.data.result.total / itemsPerPage);
                });
            },
            filterOnlyCapsText(value, search, item) {
              return (
                value != null &&
                search != null &&
                typeof value === "string" &&
                value.toString().toLocaleUpperCase().indexOf(search) !== -1
              );
            },
            gotoNewCategory() {
              this.$router.push("/dashboard/categorys/new");
            },
            editCategory(item) {
              this.$router.push({ name: "dashboard-categorys-edit", params: item });
            },
            deleteCategory(category) {
              this.categoryIdForDelete = category.id;
              this.editedIndex = this.categorys.indexOf(category);
              this.dialogDelete = true;
            },
        
            deleteCategoryConfirm() {
              this.categorys.splice(this.editedIndex, 1);
              this.$axios
                .delete("api/category/delete?id=" + this.categoryIdForDelete)
                .then((response) => {
                  if (response.data.status === "success") {
                    this.$toast.show(response.data.message, {
                      theme: "toasted-primary",
                      position: "bottom-left",
                      type: "success",
                      duration: 2000,
                    });
                  } else {
                    let list = [];
                    $.each(response.data.message, function (key, value) {
                      list.push(value);
                    });
                    this.$toast.show(list, {
                      theme: "toasted-primary",
                      position: "bottom-left",
                      type: "error",
                      duration: 4000,
                    });
                  }
                });
              this.closeDelete();
            },
        
            closeDelete() {
              this.dialogDelete = false;
              this.$nextTick(() => {
                this.editedIndex = -1;
              });
            },
          },
          mounted() {
            this.readDataFromAPI();
          },
          filters: {
            striphtmltag: function (value) {
              var div = document.createElement("div");
              div.innerHTML = value;
              var text = div.textContent || div.innerText || "";
              return text;
            },
          },
        };
        </script>
        <style lang="scss" scoped>
        * {
          font-family: YekanBakh !important;
          letter-spacing: normal !important;
        }
        
        button {
          &:focus {
            outline: none !important;
          }
        }
        
        .elevation-1 {
          box-shadow: 0 0.46875rem 2.1875rem rgba(4, 9, 20, 0.03),
            0 0.9375rem 1.40625rem rgba(4, 9, 20, 0.03), 0 0.25rem 0.53125rem rgba(4, 9, 20, 0.05),
            0 0.125rem 0.1875rem rgba(4, 9, 20, 0.03) !important;
          margin: 15px;
        }
        </style>
```

filterable not pass to API variable.

but in option for sortable :

groupBy: Array(0)
groupDesc: Array(0)
itemsPerPage: 10
multiSort: false
mustSort: false
page: 1
sortBy: Array(0)
sortDesc: Array(0)

Comment: how are you fetching data in vue component. Please share code.

Comment: sortable ok. orderBy == variable ... but filterable not work

Comment: if you share backend api code, and expect to help in frontend.. no one can help you :) you need to share component code..

Comment: you did no share how you using vuetify data table

Comment: add all code . please check .

Comment: v-model for search should be search => v-model="search"

Comment: change to search but not work .

Comment: sorry my mistake.. you have overridden that in data-table props => :search="filter".. so it should work with filter model as well..

Comment: not work brother .

Comment: We need to see the complete component code to be able to help. Especially the data section. Please edit the question and add both the template and the script parts from your component.

Comment: add complete component . please check

Comment: @MAW no answer ????

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using **server-items-length**. For Vuetify, this means you will be responsible for filtering and sorting the data in the source/back-end (the API call response data will be returning the filtered and sorted result)

As mentioned in [Vuetify Data Table documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#server-side-paginate-and-sort), you must implement your own filtration and sorting logic when using **server-items-length**.

**Here is what you can do**

1. Update your readDataFromAPI method to include the "search" data property in the request parameters to your API.
2. You can add another watcher for the data property "search", and call the method readDataFromAPI in it **(I don't like this implementation, as it will be calling the back-end with each character, which will be an expensive operation. Still depends on your use case)**

```
search(val) {
    this.readDataFromAPI()
},
```

**A better implementation** is to add an event listener to the append icon on the search text-field to call the readDataFromAPI (Make sure you are not calling it with an empty search value)

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="search"
    append-icon="mdi-magnify"
    @click:append="readDataFromAPI()"
    placeholder="Type your search and press Enter"
    @keydown.enter="readDataFromAPI()"
    label="search"
    single-line
    hide-details
></v-text-field>
```

3. In your API, do the filtration and sorting and return the result to the front-end, which should be what you are expecting.

Good luck.

Comment: Can we convert  @click  to  on change ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the change event, but it will not fire until the user navigates away from the search box! And the user will not expect this.

Comment: You can also add a @keydown.enter event to trigger the search logic by pressing the Enter key. I updated the answer to show this. See the v-text-field part.

Comment: LOOOL thank you. best answer. i used @input="" worked.